# "Must be already floating point" when converting an audio file into wav file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, naudio

Here I have a code for covering a audio file into wav format for better quality and reducing file size. Here I am using naudio file compression source code and I got an exception when I try to convert that file.

> Must be already floating point

```
public string ConvertToWAV(string tempFilePath, string tempFileName, string audioType)
{
    //Try to transform the file, if it fails use the original file            
    FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(tempFilePath + tempFileName);
    byte[] fileData = new byte[fileInfo.Length];
    fileData = File.ReadAllBytes(tempFilePath + tempFileName);
    ISampleProvider sampleProvider;
    try
    {
        if (audioType.ToLower().Contains("wav"))
        {
            try
            {
                using (MemoryStream wav = new MemoryStream(fileData))
                {
                    WaveStream stream = new WaveFileReader(wav);

                    WaveFormat target = new WaveFormat();

                    var s = new RawSourceWaveStream(new MemoryStream(), new WaveFormat(8000, 16, 1));
                    var c = new WaveFormatConversionStream(WaveFormat.CreateALawFormat(8000, 1), s);

                    sampleProvider = new WaveToSampleProvider(c);

                    WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile16(tempFilePath + tempFileName, sampleProvider);

                    wav.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //We couldn't convert the file, continue with the original file.                        
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    return Convert.ToBase64String(fileData);
}
```

Comment: Kindly please reformat your question so it can be easily read.

Comment: @Hendry hope  u can read it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at last i got a solution for this issue ie, need to add kind of additional feature named Media Foundation for the better working in Windows Server 2012.

Use the Add Roles and Features wizard from the Server Manager. Skip through to Features and select Media Foundation

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple problems with the code and the concept in general.

First, you're ignoring the `WaveFormat` of the input file.  I'm guessing that you're assuming it's 8K, 16-bit, 1 channel based on the line where you create `var s`, but this is not a guarantee.

Second, you don't need a `MemoryStream` or `RawSourceWaveStream`.  `WaveFileReader` is a `WaveStream`, and is suitable for any "next-stage" NAudio wave processor.

Third (and this is most likely your exception): The NAudio Wave processors and converters don't like A-Law (or u-Law) in the `WaveFormat`.  A-Law (and u-Law) is technically not PCM data.  As such, they're not the "wave" data that NAudio likes to play with.

Ok, with all that said, here are some suggestions.  There are very particular A-Law and u-Law encoders in the `NAudio.Codecs` namespace.  Oddly enough, they're named `ALawEncoder` and `MuLawEncoder`.  These things are *not* stream-compatible, so we want to make them compatible.

I've added a class at the end here that does just that: Creates an `IWaveProvider` that actually spits out a stream A-Law or u-Law.  Here's the test code that makes use of the new class.  The test code does the following:

1. Reads an input file using `MediaFoundationReader` (I like this one)
2. Converts whatever the input format is into 16-bit PCM (while keeping the channel count) using `MediaFoundationResampler`.  Note that this means that your input file does not have to have same format as the A-law output, so it'll convert pretty much anything.
3. Feeds that new 16-bit PCM stream to the custom "ALaw-to-IWaveProvider" converter class.
4. Writes the `IWaveProvider`-compatible A-Law output to a wave file.

I use the `MediaFoundation` classes here because they don't seem to be as particular about wave formats as the ACM-based ones.

```
    static void ConversionTest( string _outfilename, string _infilename )
    {
        try
        {
            using( var reader = new MediaFoundationReader(_infilename) )
            {
                // Create a wave format for 16-bit pcm at 8000 samples per second.
                int channels = reader.WaveFormat.Channels;
                int rate = 8000;
                int rawsize = 2;
                int blockalign = rawsize * channels; // this is the size of one sample.
                int bytespersecond = rate * blockalign;
                var midformat =
                    WaveFormat.CreateCustomFormat( WaveFormatEncoding.Pcm,
                                                   rate,
                                                   channels,
                                                   bytespersecond,
                                                   blockalign,
                                                   rawsize * 8 );

                // And a conversion stream to turn input into 16-bit PCM.
                var midstream = new MediaFoundationResampler(reader, midformat);
                //var midstream = new WaveFormatConversionStream(midformat, reader);

                // The output stream is our custom stream.
                var outstream = new PcmToALawConversionStream(midstream);


                WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile(_outfilename, outstream);
            }
        }
        catch( Exception _ex )
        {
        }
    }
```

---

And here's the class that converts 16-bit PCM into A-Law or u-Law.  At the end are specializations for A-Law or u-Law:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Encodes 16-bit PCM input into A- or u-Law, presenting the output
    /// as an IWaveProvider.
    /// </summary>
    public class PcmToG711ConversionStream : IWaveProvider
    {
        /// <summary>Gets the local a-law or u-law format.</summary>
        public WaveFormat WaveFormat { get { return waveFormat; } }

        /// <summary>Returns <paramref name="count"/> encoded bytes.</summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Note that <paramref name="count"/> is raw bytes.  It doesn't consider
        /// channel counts, etc.
        /// </remarks>
        /// <param name="buffer">The output buffer.</param>
        /// <param name="offset">The starting position in the output buffer.</param>
        /// <param name="count">The number of bytes to read.</param>
        /// <returns>The total number of bytes encoded into <paramref name="buffer"/>.</returns>
        public int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
        {
            // We'll need a source buffer, twice the size of 'count'.
            int shortcount = count*2;
            byte [] rawsource = new byte [shortcount];
            int sourcecount = Provider.Read(rawsource, 0, shortcount);
            int bytecount = sourcecount / 2;
            for( int index = 0; index < bytecount; ++index )
            {
                short source = BitConverter.ToInt16(rawsource, index*2);
                buffer[offset+index] = Encode(source);
            }
            return bytecount;
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes and A-Law or u-Law "WaveStream".  The source stream
        /// must be 16-bit PCM!
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="_encoding">ALaw or MuLaw only.</param>
        /// <param name="_sourcestream">The input PCM stream.</param>
        public PcmToG711ConversionStream( WaveFormatEncoding _encoding,
                                          IWaveProvider _provider )
        {
            Provider = _provider;
            WaveFormat sourceformat = Provider.WaveFormat;
            if( (sourceformat.Encoding != WaveFormatEncoding.Pcm) &&
                (sourceformat.BitsPerSample != 16) )
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException("Input must be 16-bit PCM.  Try using a conversion stream.");
            }

            if( _encoding == WaveFormatEncoding.ALaw )
            {
                Encode = this.EncodeALaw;
                waveFormat = WaveFormat.CreateALawFormat( _provider.WaveFormat.SampleRate,
                                                          _provider.WaveFormat.Channels) ;

            }
            else if( _encoding == WaveFormatEncoding.MuLaw )
            {
                Encode = this.EncodeMuLaw;
                waveFormat = WaveFormat.CreateMuLawFormat( _provider.WaveFormat.SampleRate,
                                                           _provider.WaveFormat.Channels) ;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException("Encoding must be A-Law or u-Law");
            }
        }


        /// <summary>The a-law or u-law encoder delegate.</summary>
        EncodeHandler Encode;
        /// <summary>a-law or u-law wave format.</summary>
        WaveFormat waveFormat;
        /// <summary>The input stream.</summary>
        IWaveProvider Provider;

        /// <summary>A-Law or u-Law encoder delegate.</summary>
        /// <param name="_sample">The 16-bit PCM sample to encode.</param>
        /// <returns>The encoded value.</returns>
        delegate byte EncodeHandler( short _sample );

        byte EncodeALaw( short _sample )
        {
            return ALawEncoder.LinearToALawSample(_sample);
        }
        byte EncodeMuLaw( short _sample )
        {
            return MuLawEncoder.LinearToMuLawSample(_sample);
        }
    }


    public class PcmToALawConversionStream : PcmToG711ConversionStream
    {
        public PcmToALawConversionStream( IWaveProvider _provider )
          : base(WaveFormatEncoding.ALaw, _provider)
        {
        }
    }

    public class PcmToMuLawConversionStream : PcmToG711ConversionStream
    {
        public PcmToMuLawConversionStream( IWaveProvider _provider )
          : base(WaveFormatEncoding.MuLaw, _provider)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: used your code ...it works localhost but run in iis server I got a error like '' Unable to load DLL 'mfplat.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)".

Comment: @Bob C 
used your code ...it works localhost but run in iis server I got a error like '' Unable to load DLL 'mfplat.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)"

Comment: @JerryJohn - That may or may not be an NAudio thing.  There's no NAudio assembly named 'mfplat.dll', but it *could* be related to the `MediaFoundation` classes.  Try replacing those with "normal" NAudio classes (like `WaveFileReader`, etc.) and see if it loads then.  Alternately, just write stubs for this code in another assembly (i.e. don't use any NAudio) and see if that also exhibits the exception.

Comment: @JerryJohn - It looks like Mark Heath also answered in your question thread.