# How to use FadeOut function

Tags: c#, naudio

I am trying to use the fadeout function in NAudio. However, I cannot understand the meaning of signatures of function. I have no idea about buffer, offset and sourceSamplesRead.

```
private void FadeOut(float[] buffer, int offset, int sourceSamplesRead)
    {
        int sample = 0;
        while (sample < sourceSamplesRead)
        {
            float multiplier = 1.0f - (fadeSamplePosition / (float)fadeSampleCount);
            for (int ch = 0; ch < source.WaveFormat.Channels; ch++)
            {
                buffer[offset + sample++] *= multiplier;
            }
            fadeSamplePosition++;
            if (fadeSamplePosition > fadeSampleCount)
            {
                fadeState = FadeState.Silence;
                // clear out the end
                ClearBuffer(buffer, sample + offset, sourceSamplesRead - sample);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

The documentation of NAudio is [here](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/blob/master/NAudio/Wave/SampleProviders/FadeInOutSampleProvider.cs).
I find the explanation of the parameters in other functions, but still cannot understand them.

Can anyone explain it to me? An example of using it can be perfect.

Comment: did u chk? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9468083/fading-sound-in-out-using-naudio

Comment: @DanielB yes, I did. It is useless for me. The answer is about fade out in a period, which is using BeginFadeOut function. I want to fade out at any moment.

Comment: @DanielB oh right, i get a new idea by your tip! Thanks, man!

Comment: Good luck @JiekeWei

Comment: Put your solution as an answer if it is way different than the link I suggested

Comment: @Daniel B, the basic idea set that period to 0

Comment: So I flagged it as duplicate

Answer (score 0):

The answer is use beginfadeout method with period of 0